# Efficiently Sliding or Hiding Form Fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Let's say that I have a form with a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu has two options. If the user chooses the second option, three additional fields that were previously invisible become visible. This is how one might implement that with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_dropdown').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'option2') {
            $('#foo, #bar, #baz').slideDown();
        }
        else {
            $('#foo, #bar, #baz').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem with this method is that when the page is first loaded and the dropdown menu has the first option selected by default, the user might see the three fields sliding up, which might look jarring. So here's another way to do the same thing, but without the problem I just described:

```
function dropdown_handler(animate) {
    if (animate == true) {
        if ($('#my_dropdown').val() == 'option2') {
            $('#foo, #bar, #baz').slideDown();
        }
        else {
            $('#foo, #bar, #baz').slideUp();
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($('#my_dropdown').val() == 'option2') {
            $('#foo, #bar, #baz').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#foo, #bar, #baz').hide();
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    dropdown_handler(false);

    $('#my_dropdown').change(function() {
        dropdown_handler(true);
    });
});
```

The problem with this method, though, is that it seems rather bloated. How can this problem be solved efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You can just trigger the change on page load

```
 $('#my_dropdown').change(function() {
         if ($(this).val() == 'option2') {
            $('#foo, #bar, #baz').slideDown();
        }
        else {
            $('#foo, #bar, #baz').slideUp();
        }
 }).change();
```

Also you need to style this in your CSS .. Which makes sure these elements are hidden when the page loads the first time..

```
#foo, #bar, #baz 
{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: What about users with JavaScript disabled?

Comment: Thinking about it more, if you're inclined to support users with JavaScript disabled, add another stylesheet within a `<noscript>` and have that stylesheet undo the hiding. This really depends on your needs, though. For example, on a failed form submission, if the second value is selected by default (meaning the three fields should be visible), your stylesheet that hides the field will be undesirable.